# knockout js observable array removing all items

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to knockout js. I am trying to remove an item from knockout observable array. But the remove function is removing all the items in the array. Can anybody help me on this?

The following is how my viewmodel looks like

```
function ReservationsViewModel() {
var self = this;
 self.availableMeals = ko.observableArray([
    { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
    { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
    { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
]);    


self.seats = ko.observableArray([]);


self.addSeat = function() {
    self.seats.push(self.availableMeals());
}
self.removeSeat = function(seat) { self.seats.remove(seat) }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

Here is the js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pQN32/

Thanks,

Praveen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `self.availableMeals()`, you get *the same Array object* back. Not *an object with the same properties and values*, but *the same object*. That means that `self.seats` contains multiple copies of the same object.

Knockout's `remove` function removes all items that are `===` to the argument you pass in, which in this case means that it will remove *all* items from the source array since they are all identical.

Since you are not using the actual pushed value anywhere, you can just push a dummy value instead:

```
self.addSeat = function() {
    self.seats.push({});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @DCoder said, you add same object to the array every time. and the removal function removes all the repeating object in the array.

Your code is half way of what you try to do.

For you to start, here is an updated jsfiddle doing what you want (I think).

http://jsfiddle.net/pQN32/5/

BTW, if your `availableMeals` never change, you don't need a `ko.observableArray`

**HTML**

```
<h2>Your seat reservations (<span data-bind="text: seats().length"></span>)</h2>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Price</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, optionsText: 'mealName', value: meal"></select></td>
            <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeSeat">Remove</a></td>

        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>

<input data-bind="value: customerName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" placeHolder="Customer Name"/>
<select data-bind="options: availableMeals, optionsText: 'mealName', value: selectedMeal, optionsCaption: 'Select a meal...'"></select>
<button data-bind="click: addSeat, enable: seats().length < 5 && selectedMeal() && customerName() && customerName().length > 0">Reserve another seat</button>
```

**JS**

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);

    self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function() {
        var price = self.meal().price;
        return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";        
    });    
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];

    self.selectedMeal = ko.observable();
    self.customerName = ko.observable();

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Operations
    self.addSeat = function() {
        self.seats.push(new SeatReservation(self.customerName(), self.selectedMeal()));

        // reset inputs
        self.customerName(undefined);
        self.selectedMeal(undefined);
    }
    self.removeSeat = function(seat) { self.seats.remove(seat) }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```